# Could not load file or assembly 'Mysql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, mysql.data

I am getting this error while running my web application in visual studio 2012, with MySQL version 5.2.47 CE:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find 
the file specified.
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: this error means the reference assembly Mysql.Data 6.6.5 is not present with the executing assembly.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but... I just had a similar problem due to the fact that the MySQL installer added a bunch of crap to my machine.config file, some of which broke a web app that wasn't even using MySQL. So there's a slight chance that an erroneous reference in your machine.config file is causing this error.